# optimized grid for rectangular items

Tags: algorithm, math, layout, mathematical-optimization

I have N rectangular items with an aspect ratio Aitem (X:Y).
I have a rectangular display area with an aspect ratio Aview

The items should be arranged in a table-like layout (i.e. r rows, c columns).

what is the ideal grid rows x columns, so that individual items are largest?
(rows * colums >= N, of course - i.e. there may be "unused" grid places).

A simple algorithm could iterate over rows = 1..N, calculate the required number of columns, and keep the row/column pair with the largest items.

I wonder if there's a non-iterative algorithm, though (e.g. for Aitem = Aview = 1, rows / cols can be approximated by sqrt(N)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: I couldn't quite understand Frédéric's answer, so I worked the problem out myself and came up with what appears to be the same solution. I figured I might as well explain what I did in case it is helpful.

First I normalized the aspect ratio of the view to that of the items. (I'm assuming you don't want to rotate the items.)

```
a = (view_width/view_height) / (item_width/item_height)
```

Now packing a rectangle of width/height ratio `a` with squares is equivalent to packing the view with items. The ideal case would be for our grid (of squares now) to fill the rectangle completely, which would give us

```
a = c/r
```

where `r` and `c` are the numbers of rows and columns:

```
N = r*c
```

Multiplying/dividing these two equations gives us

```
N*a = c^2              N/a = r^2
c = sqrt(N*a)          r = sqrt(N/a)
```

If the grid is perfect, `r` and `c` will be integers, but if not, you have to try the three options Frédéric mentioned and keep the one where `r*c` is smallest but still more than `N`:

- `floor(r), ceil(c)`
- `ceil(r),  floor(c)`
- `ceil(r),  ceil(c)`

Comment: Thanks for your detailed comments. I still have some cases where the brute force search "looks better" than these results of yours / Frederics suggestion. Maybe I'm still doign somethign wrogn with rounding, though... I 'm playing around with this only part - time.

Comment: A decade later, but this answer saved me a lot of trouble and made the program in my head possible. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution can be easily improved to handle the generic case :

If we (temporary) forget the need to have an integer number of rows and columns, we have

rows * columns = N

x = aitem * y

aview = rows * x = rows * aitem * y

1 = columns * y = (N/rows) * ( aview / [aitem*rows]) = N * aview /(aitem * rows²)

hence rows=sqrt(N *aview/aitem) and columns = N/rows = sqrt(N * aitem / aview)

Then ceil(rows) and ceil(columns) is a solution while floor(rows) and floor(columns) are too small to be a solution together (if rows and columns are not integers). This leaves 3 possible solutions :

- floor(rows) ceil(columns)
- ceil(rows) floor(columns)
- ceil(rows) ceil (columns)

**edited** to correct the equations. The first result was wrong (see comments)

Comment: I think [aitem*aview] in your final equations is a typo. What about the case where N=2, aview=6, aitem=3. You would end up with too many columns.

Comment: It's not a typo. It's a mistake in the first equations, where I've taken opposite  definitions of aview and aitem. It's embarrassing as my initial formula was not homogeneous (yes, I'm a physicist) and the error appears on a simple test case.

Thanks for pointing it.

Now, we have 2 rows and 1 column for your testcase, as expected

Answer (score 0):

Good question. If your view has dimensions A x B (fixed) and your items have dimensions a x b (variable, to be maximized), then you need:

`trunc(A / a) * trunc(B / b) >= N`

I have no idea how to solve this though - the trunc is the tricky part, as it's non-linear.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the answers to this question to work for me, but I found a neat implementation to a similar question from [Neptilo](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2570649/722611). It didn't work for rectangles though, only squares. So I applied the idea from [mckeed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2480939/1318145) to normalise the rectangle and then follow the algorithm for squares.

The result is the `fitToContainer()`  function. Give it the number of rectangles to fit `n`, the `containerWidth` and `containerHeight` and the original `itemWidth` and `itemHeight`. In case items have no original width and height, use `itemWidth` and `itemHeight` to specify the desired ratio of the items.

For example `fitToContainer(10, 1920, 1080, 16, 9)` results in `{nrows: 4, ncols: 3, itemWidth: 480, itemHeight: 270}`, so four columns and 3 rows of 480 x 270 (pixels, or whatever the unit is).

And to fit 10 squares in the same example area of 1920x1080 you could call `fitToContainer(10, 1920, 1080, 1, 1)` resulting in `{nrows: 2, ncols: 5, itemWidth: 384, itemHeight: 384}`.

```
function fitToContainer(n, containerWidth, containerHeight, itemWidth, itemHeight) {
    // We're not necessarily dealing with squares but rectangles (itemWidth x itemHeight),
    // temporarily compensate the containerWidth to handle as rectangles
    containerWidth = containerWidth * itemHeight / itemWidth;
    // Compute number of rows and columns, and cell size
    var ratio = containerWidth / containerHeight;
    var ncols_float = Math.sqrt(n * ratio);
    var nrows_float = n / ncols_float;

    // Find best option filling the whole height
    var nrows1 = Math.ceil(nrows_float);
    var ncols1 = Math.ceil(n / nrows1);
    while (nrows1 * ratio < ncols1) {
        nrows1++;
        ncols1 = Math.ceil(n / nrows1);
    }
    var cell_size1 = containerHeight / nrows1;

    // Find best option filling the whole width
    var ncols2 = Math.ceil(ncols_float);
    var nrows2 = Math.ceil(n / ncols2);
    while (ncols2 < nrows2 * ratio) {
        ncols2++;
        nrows2 = Math.ceil(n / ncols2);
    }
    var cell_size2 = containerWidth / ncols2;

    // Find the best values
    var nrows, ncols, cell_size;
    if (cell_size1 < cell_size2) {
        nrows = nrows2;
        ncols = ncols2;
        cell_size = cell_size2;
    } else {
        nrows = nrows1;
        ncols = ncols1;
        cell_size = cell_size1;
    }

    // Undo compensation on width, to make squares into desired ratio
    itemWidth = cell_size * itemWidth / itemHeight;
    itemHeight = cell_size;
    return { nrows: nrows, ncols: ncols, itemWidth: itemWidth, itemHeight: itemHeight }
}
```