# Calculate biggest size of defined number of square div's inside responsive parent divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have a grid of square divs inside a container with variable height and width.

The number of square div's is fixed.
All square divs contain images with the same dimensions (like in the example). They should be aligned left and wrap around at the end of one row to the next. And there must be an algorithm to calculate the number of columns, rows and their biggest size to fit them all into the parent div.

Can anybody give me a tip how to calculate the maximum size of the squares that every square fit in the parent container? It looks like I have kind of a packing problem here.

My actual code to calculate the image height is:

```
var imageHeight = Math.floor((maxHeight - imageMargin) / 3);
```

Detailed code: [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/ph5qe7pu/) with JSFiddle

```js
var $container = $('.container');
var $square = $('.square');

adjustSquares();
function adjustSquares() {
 // CALCULATE MAXIMUM CONTAINER HEIGHT (as example half the window height)
  $container.removeAttr('style');
  var maxHeight = Math.floor($(window).height() / 2);
  $container.css({
    'max-height': maxHeight + 'px',
    'overflow': 'hidden'
  });

  // CALCULATE MAXIMUM IMAGE HEIGHT (according to the number of squares and the maximum container height)
  var imageMargin = $square.outerWidth(true) - $square.width();
  var imageHeight = Math.floor((maxHeight - imageMargin) / 3); // How to calculate this image height?
  $square.find('img').width(imageHeight);
  $square.find('img').height(imageHeight);

  // CALCULATE CONTAINER WIDTH (to find the maximum number of squares per row and center them)
  var maxWidth = $container.width();
  var blockWidth = $square.outerWidth(true);
  var squaresPerRow = Math.floor(maxWidth / blockWidth);
  $container.width(squaresPerRow * blockWidth);
}

var resizeTimeout;
$(window).resize(function() {
 clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
  resizeTimeout = setTimeout(adjustSquares, 200);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0; /* REMOVE inline-block SPACE */
}

.square {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="square">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="square" />
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="square" />
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="square" />
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="square" />
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="square" />
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="square" />
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="square" />
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="square" />
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="square" />
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="square" />
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="square" />
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="square" />
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="square" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It is better to add code here becoz JSFiddle is sooo slow.

Comment: remove the below code why you want to restrict for max height ?
 $container.css({
    'max-height': maxHeight + 'px',
    'overflow': 'hidden'
  });

Comment: @surajrawat I have another div underneath it and the lower div should be always visible without scrolling. It is collapsable and when it collapse the upper div should expand and the lower div is positioned on the bottom of the visible page area

Comment: @KebapBoy The answer looks okay for me. Did you try that?

Comment: @Paulie_D I forgot my credentials and created a new account. Now I remind myself that I logged in with facebook, so I deleted the old question and asked it with my real account again. Sorry for the circumstances

Comment: OK...no trouble...I knew I'd seen it before but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through all the `.square` elements. And then use the `$.each()` to set it.

```
$(function () {
  var maxHeight = 0;
  $(".square").each(function () {
    var curHt = $(this).height();
    maxHeight = (curHt > maxHeight) ? curHt : maxHeight;
  });
  $(".square").css("height", maxHeight);
});
```

Comment: Hey, maybe my explanation is a little imprecise (like my english).
My goal is not to set all squares to the size of the biggest one. All square divs contain images with the same dimensions (like in the example). They should be alligned left and wrap around at the end of one row to the next.
And there must be an algorithm to calculate the number of columns, rows and their biggest size to fit them all into the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

I did it!!

According to [this post on Math Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/466248) I managed to get a workable solution.

The algorithm I used:

```
  var containerWidth = $container.width();
  var containerHeight = Math.floor($(window).height() / 2);

  $container.css({
    'max-height': containerHeight + 'px',
    'overflow': 'hidden'
  });

  // CALCULATE MAXIMUM SQUARE SIZE, according to the number of squares and the container size
  var hw = containerHeight / containerWidth;
  var wh = containerWidth / containerHeight;

  var px = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(squareCount * hw));
  var py = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(squareCount * wh));

  var sx;
  if (Math.floor(px * wh) * px < squareCount) {
    sx = containerWidth / Math.ceil(px * wh);
  }
  else {
    sx = containerHeight / px;
  }

  var sy;
  if (Math.floor(py * hw) * py < squareCount) {
    sy = containerHeight / Math.ceil(py * hw);
  }
  else {
    sy = containerWidth / py;
  }

  var squareDimension = Math.floor(Math.max(sx, sy) - squareMargin);
  $squares.find('img').width(squareDimension);
  $squares.find('img').height(squareDimension);
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ph5qe7pu/1/) for the updated calculation algorithm in action.

Comment: Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1575761/4473427) article covers the same problem. The answer explains the algorithm pretty understandable.