# Easy way to maximize size of square flexbox elements?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox `<div>` that contains n equally-sized subelements (also `<div>`s). These subelements are square (`aspect-ratio:1;`), but the exact height and width is unknown---they should be as large as possible. Here are the constraints:

- n will not vary.
- Height and width of the containing `<div>` might vary over time, in response to the user's actions. (I might be able to make the height constant.)
- I do not care how many rows of items there are (nor how many items there are per row). I expect that this will change if the size of the containing element changes.
- The subelements must all be 100% inside of the containing element, with no scroll bars or hidden items.
- The containing element does not need to be a flexbox, if this is better achieved in a different way.
- Every subelement needs to stay of equal size, even if that size changes.

So how can I maximize the size of the subelements? Is there an easy way to do it? Answers in pure HTML/CSS will be preferred.

Here's a rough image of what I'm trying to accomplish:[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help but I need some pictures. A picture is worth 1000 words.

Comment: Or show us what you've tried. Edit your question to include a snippet that gets as close as you can to what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you. I've added an image. (The code I have right now is a wild mess of things I've tried.)

Comment: So if there were 25 words in the first box instead of just the letter 'a', you would want the first box to grow to accommodate the 25 words, and you also want all the other boxes to grow to the same size?

Comment: The contents of the boxes don't matter here. (I'm going to be using inline SVGs to make sure that they scale properly. The contents of every box will be substantially the same.) The key is that all the boxes must be the same size. Let x be the width (and height too) of a single box. I want to maximize x, subject to the constraint that all the boxes must be visible. And that value must update dynamically if the container size changes.

Answer (score 1):

**Intermediate update 1** code redo mainly...

The CSS is commented and fairly self explanatory.

**However**

- When the size of both the parent container and the child elements are unknown, assumptions will have to be made based on the number of child elements **(n)** that are put in the parent container. I chose the easy math of **SQRT(n)** to obtain a **m*n** matrix holding **(n)** squares.
- The preview image *suggests* that there is at least some wrapping of child elements required. Therefore:

  1. Both *Flexbox Layout* and *CSS Grid* will eventually need a size, regardless whether that is a `fr` value, element `width` or `min-width`, to trigger their wrappping mechanisms.
  2. `max-content` will only define the equal `height` or `width` of elements in a single row vs. column, like the `table` mechanism does. (...however, *I still need to verify this*...)

The result of `SQRT(n)` will be the number of rows and columns of squares required within the parent. By dividing the parent `width` by `SQRT(n)`, adjusted with `(n-1) * gap` you can derive the width for each sub element.

```js
/*

    The only function of the Javascript code is to
    create a list of <div> elements based on the
    number of squares required.

*/

// Assign event listener for initial setup
window.onload = function () { resetContainer('container'); };

/*
    resetContainer()

    Remove existing squares from the container and create a
    new list of elements based on the number of kids required
*/
function resetContainer(id, kids = 1, tagName = 'div') {
/* default parameter values here for convenience */

// Any parent with passed ID
const parent = document.getElementById(id);

    // Remove the current list of squares
    while (parent.firstChild) { parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild); };

    // Create new list of squares
    for (let i = 0; i < kids; i++) {
        let child = document.createElement(tagName);
        parent.appendChild(child);
    };
};
```

```css
.container { outline: 1px dashed black } /* for debugging */

*     { box-sizing: border-box }
:root { --body-space: 0.5rem }

body {
    margin: unset;
    padding: var(--body-space);

    /* responsive font size */
    /* y=mx+b with points p1(320,14) and p2(1280,20) */
    font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.75rem);
}

:root {
    /* Defined here for easy access in range slider JS */
    --vw : 4; /* initial container size in VW, changed by user */
    --n  : 1; /* number of squares */
    --min: 0; /* minimum width of a square */
    --gap: 0; /* gap between squares */
}

.container {
    /* Slider square minimum size converted to px */
    --sq-min: calc( var(--min) * 1px);
    
    /* Calculate SQRT(n) in CSS */
    --sqr1: calc((var(--n)    + ( var(--n) / var(--n)   )) / 2);
    --sqr2: calc((var(--sqr1) + ( var(--n) / var(--sqr1))) / 2);
    --sqr3: calc((var(--sqr2) + ( var(--n) / var(--sqr2))) / 2);
    --sqr4: calc((var(--sqr3) + ( var(--n) / var(--sqr3))) / 2);
    --sqr5: calc((var(--sqr4) + ( var(--n) / var(--sqr4))) / 2);
    --sqr6: calc((var(--sqr5) + ( var(--n) / var(--sqr5))) / 2);
    --sqr7: calc((var(--sqr6) + ( var(--n) / var(--sqr6))) / 2);
    --sqr8: calc((var(--sqr7) + ( var(--n) / var(--sqr7))) / 2);
    --sqr9: calc((var(--sqr8) + ( var(--n) / var(--sqr8))) / 2);
    --sqrt: calc((var(--sqr9) + ( var(--n) / var(--sqr9))) / 2);

    /*
        --sqrt results in a number of rows and columns (m*n matrix)
        e.g. n = 100 => SQRT(n) = 10 => 10 rows, 10 columns
    */
    /*
        When gap is > 0 then we need to subtract (SQRT(n) - 1) * gap
        from the container width to calculate the final size of a square.

        minus 1, because gaps in a row/column are only between elements
        e.g. a container with 10 squares in a row will have only 9 gaps
        between them.
    */
    
    /* Calculate total gaps in a row => (SQRT(n)-1) * gap-size in 'px' */
    --total-gap: calc((var(--sqrt) - 1) * var(--gap) * 1px);

    /* square size = container width - total-gap / SQRT(n) in 'vw' */
    /* result is space available for one square in a row */
    --sq-size: calc(var(--vw) / var(--sqrt) * 1vw);

    --sq-size: calc(((var(--vw) * 1vw) - var(--total-gap)) / var(--sqrt));

    /*
        TODO: currently flawed as the SQRT(n) result must be rounded up
              to an integer to make all squares fit the parent.

              This will require JS => (Math.ceil(--sqrt)

              For now, leaving as-is with CSS only SQRT calculation...
    */

    gap: calc(var(--gap) * 1px);
    
    /* create a parental square */
    width: calc(var(--vw) * 1vw);

    /*  height: calc(var(--vw) * 1vw); /* obsolete */
    /* We are going to let the number of squares dictate the height */

    min-width: var(--sq-min);

    display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center; align-items: center;
    
    color: CornSilk;
    margin: 0 auto; /* horizontally center in view */
}

.container > * {
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-grow: 1;     /* here, but irrelevant as size is set below */

    width    : var(--sq-size); /* force to maintain calculated width */
    max-width: var(--sq-size); /* in each row of the flexbox parent  */

    min-width : calc(var(--min) * 1px); /* supercedes width and max-width */
    min-height: calc(var(--min) * 1px); /* dito height */
    
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;      /* keep it a square */
    height: var(--sq-size);    /* aspect-ratio fails in certain cases */

    /* Eye-candy */    
    display: grid; place-items: center; /* easy centering content */
    background-color: CornflowerBlue;

    /* We need the bigger of the two for some eye-candy */
    --fs: max(var(--sq-size), var(--min) * 1px);
    font-size    : calc(var(--fs) / 1.75);
    border-radius: calc(var(--fs) / 4);
}

/* A Unicode Dingbat as content */
.container > ::after { content: '\2706' }

input[type="range"] { width: 100% }
label, input        { display: block; font-size: 1em }
label,li            { margin-bottom: 0.5rem }

summary {
    font-size: 1.17em; /* equal to <h3> */
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label><b>container width</b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;[1 - 80vw] <span id="info-size"> &gt; 4vw</span>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="80" step="0.1" value="4"
           oninput="document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vw', this.value);
                    document.getElementById('info-size').innerHTML = ' > ' + this.value + 'vw';">
</label>
<label><b>number of squares (n)</b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;[1 - 196] <span id="info-squares"> &gt; 1</span>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="196" step="1" value="1"
           oninput="document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--n', this.value);
                    document.getElementById('info-squares').innerHTML = ' > ' + this.value;
                    resetContainer('container', this.value);">
</label>
<label><b>square minimum size</b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;[0 - 288px] <span id="info-min"> &gt; 0px</span>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="288" step="1" value="0"
           oninput="document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--min', this.value);
                    document.getElementById('info-min').innerHTML = ' > ' + this.value + 'px';
                    resetContainer('container',window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--n'));">
</label>
<label><b>square gaps</b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;[0 - 32px]<span id="info-gap"> &gt; 0px</span>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="32" step="1" value="0"
           oninput="document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--gap', this.value);
                    document.getElementById('info-gap').innerHTML = ' > ' + this.value + 'px';">
</label>

<br><br>
<details>
    <summary>Constraints</summary>
    <ul>
        <li>Main container size can vary in size <b>(vw)</b>, <i>user action dependent</i>, modify with slider.
        <li>Number of child elements is unknown but fixed <b>(n)</b>, define with slider.
        <li>Child elements must be equal squares at all times, <b>size = (vw - gaps) / SQRT(n)</b>.
        <li>Child elements must all be 100% inside parent, (not overflow the parent).
        <li>The parent itself must be able to stretch horizontally and vertically
            (and therefore might overflow the viewport extends).
        <li>The squares must optimally fit the parent container.
            <br> - To be able to calculate the optimal size of a square, either width,
            height or both of the parent must be known to find the optimal size of a quare.
            <br> - Alternatively, the side of a square must be known. At least,
            for <i>Flexbox Layout</i> and <i>CSS Grid</i>
            to know when to wrap a child element to the next line.
    </ul>
</details>

<br><br><br>
<div class="container" id="container">
    <!-- Child elements appended with JS based on current --n -->
</div>
```

Comment: So this sizes the boxes based on an external input (the value of a slider) ... but what if the OP wants the boxes sized based on the content, so the boxes will grow in size to accommodate the box with the largest content? I'm not sure if that's what the OP wants -- I've made a comment to try to clarify this.

Comment: Confirming what @BrettDonald said: I appreciate the work you've put into this, but it's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to maximize the size of each square box, based on what the width and height of the container are. There's no guarantee that the container is a square, nor that n is a perfect square.

Comment: Am I reading that correctly--are you calculating a square root via Newton's method? That's pretty cool!

Answer (score 1):

My solution includes JavaScript to *maximize the size of the [squares]*. I have used this as reference:

- [Resizing N # of squares to be as big as possible while still fitting into box of X by Y dimensions. (Thumbnails!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575589/resizing-n-of-squares-to-be-as-big-as-possible-while-still-fitting-into-box-of)

Here is my solution:

- It looks at the dimensions of the `.container`.
- It looks at the number of `.square` elements in the `.container`
- It then calculates the best size for the `.square` elements and sets them.

```js
window.onload = function () { 
  setSquareDimension(); 
};

function setSquareDimension() {
    const container = document.querySelector('.container');

  const containerComputedStyle = getComputedStyle(container);
  const containerPaddingLeft = Number(containerComputedStyle.paddingLeft.replace("px",""));
  const containerPaddingRight = Number(containerComputedStyle.paddingRight.replace("px",""));
  const containerPaddingTop = Number(containerComputedStyle.paddingTop.replace("px",""));
  const containerPaddingBottom = Number(containerComputedStyle.paddingBottom.replace("px",""));
  const containerGap = Number(containerComputedStyle.gap.replace("px",""));
  const containerWidth = container.clientWidth - containerPaddingLeft - containerPaddingRight;
  const containerHeight = container.clientHeight - containerPaddingTop - containerPaddingBottom; 
  
  const availableWidth = containerWidth - containerPaddingLeft - containerPaddingRight;
  const availableHeight = containerHeight - containerPaddingTop - containerPaddingBottom;
  
  const squares = container.getElementsByClassName('square');
  const nbrOfSquares = squares.length;

  let squareDim = getMaxSizeOfSquaresInContainer(nbrOfSquares, availableWidth, availableHeight) - containerGap;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    squares[i].style.width = squareDim + "px";
    squares[i].style.height = squareDim + "px";
  }
 
}

function getMaxSizeOfSquaresInContainer(nbrOfSquares, containerWidth, containerHeight) {
  let sw, sh;
  let pw = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt((nbrOfSquares * containerWidth) / containerHeight));
  if (Math.floor((pw * containerHeight) / containerWidth) * pw < nbrOfSquares) {
      sw = containerHeight / Math.ceil((pw * containerHeight) / containerWidth);
  } else {
      sw = containerWidth / pw;
  }
  let ph = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt((nbrOfSquares * containerHeight) / containerWidth));
  if (Math.floor((ph * containerWidth) / containerHeight) * ph < nbrOfSquares) {
      sh = containerWidth / Math.ceil((containerWidth * ph) / containerHeight);
  } else {
      sh = containerHeight / ph;
  }
  return Math.max(sw, sh);
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 600px; 
  height: 200px; 
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square">a</div>
  <div class="square">b</div>
  <div class="square">c</div>
  <div class="square">d</div>
  <div class="square">e</div>
  <div class="square">f</div>
  <div class="square">g</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this. The 10rem sets the minimum width for each grid column, you can adjust this bigger or smaller as desired.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10rem, 1fr));
```

More hints in [this excellent article](https://css-tricks.com/intrinsically-responsive-css-grid-with-minmax-and-min/).

```css
#d {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10rem, 1fr));
  gap: 1em;
}
#d>div {
  background-color: lime;
  border-radius: 10px;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="d">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
  <div>d</div>
  <div>e</div>
  <div>f</div>
  <div>g</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Nice! The spacing gets wonky if you change the container `div` to something like `1000px`.

Comment: Only problem is when the content inside one of the grid items gets long, that element will get taller but not wider and the others won't change size at all. Not sure if there's a way around that with grid though.

Comment: Using minimum `10rem` is a workaround I'd prefer too for triggering a wrap, but OP stated in the first line: *These subelements are square ... but the exact height and width is unknown*. Basically `2rem` could be possible too, the reason I introduced the range sliders to at least be able to test various options. BTW, I don't want to be 'right'. I think it is a fun problem and am curious where this eventually will lead as there are a few inconsistencies in the requirements I am still figuring out. Updated my answer in the mean time...

Answer (score 0):

Edit: missed the aspect-ratio thing. It works now. :-) Removed flex-grow, added aspect-ratio and provided some dimensions.

Change the `width` and `height` of the `.flex-container` CSS rule to see the result.

[Attribution - CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#aa-examples)

```css
.flex-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  /* We first create a flex layout context */
  display: flex;
  
  /* Then we define the flow direction 
     and if we allow the items to wrap 
   * Remember this is the same as:
   * flex-direction: row;
   * flex-wrap: wrap;
   */
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  
  /* Then we define how is distributed the remaining space */
  justify-content: space-around;
  
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.flex-item {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `flex-grow: 1;` is a good idea, but can it work with `aspect-ratio: 1/1;` ?

Comment: @BrettDonald - whoops - missed the aspect-ratio thing. It works now. :-) Removed flex-grow, added aspect-ratio and provided some dimensions.

Comment: But now the gaps grow wider instead of the boxes growing bigger. Don't we want *both* `flex-grow` and `aspect-ratio`?

Comment: I appreciate the work here--thank you. But I think that this isn't what I'm looking for. It doesn't appear to maximize the size of the elements--that's really key here. Choosing a size dynamically that lets the width and height of the squares be as large as possible, while still allowing everything to fit.